# Connected set cannot be written as the union of numerable proper connected separated sets.

Tags: general-topology

Is there a proof or a counterexample to such an affirmation?

For example, we know that no finite union of proper connected sets is connected.

Can it happen that given any connected set, and given a numerable collection of proper connected separated subsets of X, that X is equal to the union of such a collection?

In other words, given a connected set $X$, is $X$ is always bigger than any union of proper connected separated sets?

Comment: $$\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,0) \cup [0,\infty)$$

Comment: I think that I should edit my question. Thanks.

Comment: How does your edit invalidate the example in my previous comment?

Comment: Note the word "separated."

Comment: Define separated.

Comment: A, B are separated if $cl_X(A)\cap B = \varnothing$ AND $A\cap cl_X(B)=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $X$ be any countably infinite set, with the cofinite topology.

Then $X$ is connected, and also, $X$ is the countable union of its singleton subsets, which are proper connected sets.

Also, any two distinct singletons sets are separated.